# ajax result differ if it is placed inside a variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi and Good day to all,

I have a dilemma which includes javasript and ajax. I have an ajax code which is show below (not the whole code but part of the code, so some brackets might be missing but it works correctly)

```
$.ajax({
  url: "ajax/month.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: { telcos: telco, start: sdate, end: edate, regions: region},

  success: function (dataofconfirm) {
    var month = dataofconfirm;
    alert(month);
```

In the ajax above (of course it was inside a javascript), when i tried to alert it this is the result

[image]

Then I tried to place a monthly sales chart like the one below
This is the code (javascript) of my sales chart

```
var months = month;
    // Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.
    var salesChartCanvas = $("#salesChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    // This will get the first returned node in the jQuery collection.
    var salesChart = new Chart(salesChartCanvas);
    var salesChartData = {
      labels: months,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "SMART",
          fillColor: "rgb(255,40,40)",
          strokeColor: "rgb(255,40,40)",
          pointColor: "rgb(253,16,16)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgb(220,220,220)",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
```

Above code is just a portion again so some brackets might be missing.
Notice that I placed the ajax result inside **var months**

But when the javascript loads and finishes its process the result is like the one below

[image]

Instead of a certain number per months will be shown it now displays that certain number per letter in the month variable.

How Can i fix this. The result mut be like the one below(this is just a static so its correct)

[image]

This is whar the **labels:months** should look like
**labels: ["August", "September", "October", "November"],**

Comment: Doesn't need the months amount be equal to the amount of data rows to create a nice graph?

Comment: is the `var months = month;` block of code inside the success function?? or wait for that ajax to finish in some other way?

Comment: You did not parse. `JSON.parse(month)` will do the trick.

Comment: I tried that too.....result is the same. same as the second photo.

Comment: i'm not particualrly good in JSON.parse nicovank. Where should i place them? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ajax response is returning a string, not an array.

In JavaScript (and most languages) a string can be treated as an array of characters. Which is what is happening here.

Instead you need to parse the returned data as JSON, you can do this one of two ways:

```
 JSON.parse(month); // <-- the result returned from the server
```

Or using jQuery $.ajax

```
 $.ajax({
     url: "ajax/month.php",
     dataType: "json", // <-- response will be an object, not a string
     type: 'POST',
     data: { telcos: telco, start: sdate, end: edate, regions: region},
```

Comment: Thanks in a million and one ways Richard. You saved the day.